# How to solve inverse problem for a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse-problems, system-identification

Please, suggests a couple of not complicated textbooks regarding the inverse problem for ODE systems (say, Lotka-Volterra predator-prey system). Namely, I would like to know how to recover parameters of equations on the base of observations of the system.

Comment: Compute the observed derivatives at sample points via divided differences or some better fitting methods and treat the coefficient determination as a linear regression problem.

Comment: Thanks, I heard earlier, that regression analysis is used for that problem, but would like to read some textbooks on this matter.